# getting location of element identified by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, while-loop

I have the following HTML for a couple of icon links (the "url here" 's are actual urls in my code):

```
<div class="horizontal-icons" id="div">

    <a href="url here" target="_blank" class="livepreview" data-position="bottom">
        <div><h4>diary</h4></div>
    </a>

    <a href="url here" target="_blank" class="livepreview" data-position="bottom">
        <div><h4>art</h4></div>
    </a>

    <a href="url here" target="_blank" class="livepreview" data-position="bottom">
       <div><h4>other stuff</h4></div>
    </a>

</div>
```

I'm in the process of trying to create javascript that will generate a live preview on hover over any of the icons ("a" elements), but positioned in exactly the same spot as the icon being hovered over. So my first task for the script has been to identify the position of the "a" element upon hover. However, my code is returning "NaN" values for the X and Y coordinates I'm trying to find.

Could anyone identify why my code isn't working as intended? For the script, I've taken a cue from the code outlined by by Kirupa at http://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm and by api.jquery at https://api.jquery.com/hover/:

```
    function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0,
        yPosition = 0;

    while (element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}

$(".livepreview").hover(
    function () {
        var livePreviewElement = $(this);
        var position = getPosition(livePreviewElement);
        alert("The image is located at: " + position.x + ", " + position.y);
    }
);
```

You can see the elements and code implemented at 173.246.106.210. While responding, please keep in mind that I have no formal learning of Javascript. I only understand what I've cobbled together from going through a few tutorials, and I understand even less about JQuery. ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that you are passing a jQuery object and treat it as DOM object. jQuery selection `$(selector)` returns an array-like jQuery object, but not a native DOM element.

You simply need to change this

```
var livePreviewElement = $(this); 
var position = getPosition(livePreviewElement);
```

to

```
var livePreviewElement = this;
var position = getPosition(livePreviewElement);
```